# how add empty object on 2D array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have 2D NSMutableArray with my class objects.

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray2D = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [myArray addObject:cardView];
    [myArray addObject:cardView];
    [myArray addObject:cardView];

    [myArray2D addObject:myArray];
}

[[myArray2D lastObject] removeAllObjects];
```

My last object in myArray2D is has "0 objects"
Then I need remove last object in my myArray2D

```
// .... some code
```

Then I want to add this object with "0 object" back
How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "this object", because the empty array that you delete from myArray2D will be deallocated after you remove it. If you want to add an empty array to myArray2D, just alloc init a new array and add it:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray2D addObject:myArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe this is your answer

```
NSMutableArray *myArray2D = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [myArray addObject:cardView];
    [myArray addObject:cardView];
    [myArray addObject:cardView];

    [myArray2D addObject:myArray];
}

[[myArray2D lastObject] removeAllObjects];
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [myArray2D lastObject];
[myArray2D removeLastObject];
[myArray2D addObject:tmpArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty array like this: `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];`

You cannot add `nil` objects to an NSArray.